# Bad characters when replacing text in pdf using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to replace text in pdf and it's kind of replaced, this is my code

```
PDDocument doc = null;
    int occurrences = 0;
    try {
        doc = PDDocument.load("test.pdf"); //Input PDF File Name
        List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(i);
            PDStream contents = page.getContents();
            PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream());
            parser.parse();
            List tokens = parser.getTokens();
            for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
                Object next = tokens.get(j);
                if (next instanceof PDFOperator) {
                    PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator) next;
                    // Tj and TJ are the two operators that display strings in a PDF
                    if (op.getOperation().equals("Tj")) {
                        // Tj takes one operator and that is the string
                        // to display so lets update that operator
                        COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);
                        String string = previous.getString();
                        if (string.contains("Good")) {
                            string = string.replace("Good", "Bad");
                            occurrences++;
                        }
                        //Word you want to change. Currently this code changes word "Good" to "Bad"
                        previous.reset();
                        previous.append(string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                    } else if (op.getOperation().equals("TJ")) {
                        COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(j - 1);
                        COSString temp = new COSString();

                        String tempString = "";
                        for (int t = 0; t < previous.size(); t++) {

                            if (previous.get(t) instanceof COSString) {
                                tempString += ((COSString) previous.get(t)).getString();

                            }
                        }

                        temp.append(tempString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                        tempString = "";
                        tempString = temp.getString();
                        if (tempString.contains("Good")) {
                            tempString = tempString.replace("Good", "Bad");
                            occurrences++;
                        }
                        previous.clear();

                        String[] stringArray = tempString.split(" ");

                        for (String string : stringArray) {
                            COSString cosString = new COSString();
                            string = string + " ";
                            cosString.append(string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                            previous.add(cosString);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            // now that the tokens are updated we will replace the page content stream.
            PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);
            OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();
            ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
            tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);
            page.setContents(updatedStream);
        }
        System.out.println("number of matches found: " + occurrences);
        doc.save("a.pdf"); //Output file name
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReplaceTextInPDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (COSVisitorException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReplaceTextInPDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (doc != null) {
            try {
                doc.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ReplaceTextInPDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

the issue that it's replaced in a bad characters or hidden shape ( as example the bad word becomes only d character), but if i copy and paste it in another place it paste the expected word correctly,
also when i search the generated pdf for the new word it doesn't find it, but when i search with the old word it finds it in the replaced places

Comment: *Replacing text in PDFs* is not as easy as one might think: **A** Visually contiguous text is not necessarily drawn by contiguous text drawing operations, let alone by a single one. **B** The strings in the content stream are not necessarily encoded in some standard encoding, on the contrary the encoding might be an ad-hoc encoding without structure. Furthermore the text to replace may use multiple fonts, so parts of it might be differently encoded. This both complicates the search and replacement. **C** Fonts embedded in PDFs need not be complete, often only actually used glyphs are embedded.

Comment: **D** The font encoding used might even not contain enough information to determine the characters some string represents. **E** The text to later extract for a replaced string may be defined somewhere else, e.g. in **ActualText** structure element or marked content entries. **etc pp**

Comment: The problem i got now is there is specific characters don't be written correctly in experiments with different pdfs, like Iike capitals IJKZ

Comment: See item **C** above, probably the glyph for the letter you want to write simply is not there. Or see item **B**, probably the eencoding is non-standard and what you expect to be a capital letter actually represents something entirely different.

Comment: if that so, there is strangeness, that the code puts the whole pdf texts inside Strings then replaces expression in this string, and write this string again to the pdf, the whole pdf is fine except the replaced word,
i tried not to write it back and keep previous.clear(); , the text disappears from the pdf, then why the replaced word only is corrupted ?

Comment: As you have not shared the PDF you are talking about, I can merely guess. In particular, I cannot explain specific observations you describe because there are many possible reasons for something like that. In general trying to edit PDFs like you do is a waste of time because there are too many assumptions in your code. If you only plan to edit very specific PDFs, one can try and inspect their internals. If they are built along the lines of those assumption, you may be in luck.

Comment: BTW, which PDFBox version do you use? There used to be certain bugs in PDFBox (I especially have one in PDFBox 1.8.2 on my mind) which made editing PDFs even more hazardous.

Comment: PDFBOX 1.8.10, also it's a program for my employer, fortunately i found aspose library, it worked fine, except that it's not free, so the free version is printing copyrights line on the head of pdf file pages, i'll post the link in an answer

Comment: thanks for the code : +1 - I got same problem with character €. Anything else remains ok.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found aspose, this link shows how to use it to replace text in pdfs, it's easy and works perfect except that it's not free, so the free version is printing copyrights line on the head of pdf file pages
http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfjava/Replace+Text+in+Pages+of+a+PDF+Document

Comment: This isn't an answer. This is as if someone asks a Windows question, and the answer is "I bought an Apple".

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Agree that this is not an answer. But I really wonder how they possibly can do that. Although I got reasons why you opt out replacing text from PdfBox's feature box, it sounds interesting how it can be achievable.